# What is daemon user on mac?

Tags: permission, user-account, webserver, daemons

I installed XAMPP on mac and it uses the user daemon. I have trouble accessing an external site that I have setup for which I am getting "Access Denied" error.
This is likely because daemon user does not have access to this folder. I can't see this user among user users. I have looked everywhere.
Where I can access/change permission to this user?

I came to know about Daemons and Agents on mac. Are they related?
How would I add this user to directory. Because when I click get info a folder, this user (daemon) is not listed.

Comment: Why not grant the user permission on the files in question? Also, what does the installation guide for XAMPP recommend for your version of the software?

Comment: It uses XAMPP user. It does not have any particular recommendation. I can probably run XAMPP under my own administrator login but I want to know how to set permission for this deamon user and what actually it is.

Comment: You say "accessing an external site " because "does not have access to this folder" How is an external site a folder?

Comment: External site outside XAMPP's htdocs folder. By default pages are severed from htdocs but you can setup external folders that serves pages as well. External folder: Any folder other than htdoc folder.

Answer (score 2):

Ref : [XAMPP on Mac OSX: Why running as 'daemon'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25821536/xampp-on-mac-osx-why-running-as-daemon)

In */Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/etc/httpd.conf* change

```
User daemon
Group daemon
```

to

```
User YourName
Group YourGroup
```

Fixed!